# Возможно ли вставить boost::intrusive::list в boost::intrusive::list?

Tags: c++, list, boost, linked-list

Возможно ли вставить  boost::intrusive::list в boost::intrusive::list ? У меня возникла потребность объединить 2 списка, без всякой логики и сортировок, очевидно это можно сделать за O(1) просто вставив первую ноду списка2 в список1. Вопрос только как это сделать, в библиотеке я нашел только метод merge, который работает за O(N). Есть ли возможность вставить список в список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть метод `splice`. Сложность у него константная, если контейнер имеет трейт `constant_time_size<false>`, и линейная в противном случае.

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/list_hook.hpp>

struct t_Foo;

using t_FooHook = ::boost::intrusive::list_base_hook
<
    ::boost::intrusive::link_mode<::boost::intrusive::auto_unlink>
>;

using t_FooList = ::boost::intrusive::list
<
    ::t_Foo
,   ::boost::intrusive::base_hook<::t_FooHook>
,   ::boost::intrusive::constant_time_size<false>
>;

struct t_Foo: public ::t_FooHook
{
    int value{};

    explicit t_Foo(int const initial_value)
    :   ::t_FooHook{}, value{initial_value}
    {}
};

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    ::t_Foo f0{12};
    ::t_Foo f1{34};
    ::t_Foo f2{56};
    ::t_Foo f3{78};
    ::t_FooList list1{};
    ::t_FooList list2{};
    list1.push_back(f0);
    list1.push_back(f1);
    list2.push_back(f2);
    list2.push_back(f3);
    list2.splice(++(list2.begin()), list1, list1.begin(), list1.end());
    assert(0 == list1.size());
    assert(4 == list2.size());
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIABykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAMykAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn6BdpgOWQ1NBCWRMXEJyQqNza15HeP9YYPlw0kAlLaoXsTI7BzmiWHI3lgA1CaJbtGo6QQA9GEExF4ZAG6YV7R4YwB0CCkpJ9gmGgAgjs9gdMMdTudLjdBPcni83mMAPoIC4Aay%2BPz%2BAOBQLG9wchwISIAYhcTlYgTiHmFgETSRcABLoiEAEUOIBAULGnNucLwz05iOJ0SYShR6JxJzcOMOco5XIuPJAfJpgpAbwYaKRLAwmGlnO5BF5sLV7BATC8RCRXgYmrR2KpiX%2BiUpuMBNKM9LJqFCYzZCqNJruZqF7wIUtOsvlnOJPpxpBjisuwf56tF4tRqAdp1jDNQzOzjsBiblhqVxpVpvhnLQDDGhmJjjYSIyAC99acqGIlMXsa6pXiQ4S4xcQIcUl5om9kArRwXJVSAOxu%2BWHW6HR5iLz6lcmJesimDwFrzCqFIzwjei4QDd1/1hTJiJFb7yYJbRstJ%2BeFh17g%2BJq%2BO77hYj6OM%2BQG7oeQJriB%2B7QcCB5HlSVJJKCXhHNKogKEozR9kCG4sEwYQQB%2By6rt%2B%2BaHFQGggVwZjwchJ6UT61FcCBiSSIxA4wSxFzUQxK4AKwAGzcRRZYgPO1GJCBS7%2BOJn5zvmfoEIcwrsf%2Bh48cxknzqp6nhoJVhITpa4aR8k4KAgSKisgaLUBoH5mfKFlWTZdkOVQXDORJhljGYlkPB5TD2dQZi%2BUpwqBe5tmhV5iSRbxcrRR8CgXngmwQNY1gQKlsTACRSwrP5BBcImFkFUVFXhlwHyuKRSW6YcYq4QQEAaGyJzshZ7aYI1TFrq1cTtZIXWJD1RlpXgHYDS5crEJgBDrAwhy0Tp8EcCstCcEJvB%2BBwWikKgnAypY1iHAoawbOCOw8KQxqHVtKxoiAiQAJwfGYZjvRoZiSO9kiJIkXAaCJIn6Jwkj7ZovAnRwvAKCAGgPbDKxwLAMCICgqAsCkdBxOQlBoHjBPxMA9HlTQtAEHESMQNEsOkNEYRNAAnpw90k2wggAPJ2hzT2kFgRFGOIQv4It3TPEjQtnl0VpbPdtw1EzbzRMQ7MeFgTN3HgLCc1tfAGMACgAGp4JgADuvMpIwhsyIIIhiOwUiO/IShqEzujlQYRgoDllj6Hg0RI7AzBsMmYykM88TcEu73PcdKR1PWnAALTp2M6DdaY52WFwS6HOnADqYi0IjNRdKnLgMO4nhtHoIRzGUFR6GkGSp5MfjlR3RQMAMrfDOVnTdPUMzd3oo%2Bp70zSD0M8QjxPDd5EvfTzwsi8rFd6ybHodyYErRs7Rwe2kAdR3w6o/gienIljcAyCzvRHxcIcEBnVYQeHLghAkMcSRyqHA8KTegxAAEgyWLwR6WhiqkFekJFGJ9oakANog8%2BTN4aI2RqjJ66MsYQCQGsAgk4CBEwgCTfGYCIisC2NfW%2B99DiP2foFe6mB8BEGIHgdAeh%2BBO1EOIN2fCPYqHUELH2pAraaxSIbbau0YZC3hrzK0pDDioCoIcehd8H5P0OC/N%2BH9cZULiBAny0C0YrAQJgJgWB4ikUhhwFBaCUYXzhpwbBKMYFJ1emYJcHwgZLnvoXJIiRRIaF9pwRICjL7uNwbA0gGNsby2QFaEg5Cmim2UIYGoQhURWwOlzIxdAmCpyyeEWguTUD5KZpQsmIAKZmHKrUsByjhB5NcUEVQXRATEFNrE5JDR8AHV4MI52gjpDCMUKI72eg/bGEDjYdWYcoAR3YEaGOwx46JzgagFOWRZaI2unvJeQyyk5PaQ7A%2BR9JHSNkQ4s%2BHT4bYC6Skzhmib7aKYbo/R79P7WETL/N5d0oFxO8W9RIHxgZQuhTChxKDHmxKRp4ixDizDRLcQjUFcDY4ZGcJIIAA%3D%3D%3D)